# OnScroll selected date display in other listitem too

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, baseadapter, android-datepicker

I have adapter for listview,when i click on `checkbox` i open alert dailog,in my alert dailog i have datepicker,now whatever date i select i need to display in my textview of listitem,i am able to display text,but the issue is if i select date for first listitem and then i scroll i can figure out that,in my 6th listitem it is also selected

Mybaseadapter

```
public class CustomAdapterPooja extends BaseAdapter {
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private final Context context;
        private List<ModelPooja> listData;

        public CustomAdapterPooja(Context mainActivity, List<ModelPooja> listData) {
            context = mainActivity;
            this.listData = listData;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            dtlist=new ArrayList<String>();
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poojaselection, null);
                holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaname);
                holder.showsdates = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selecteddatess);
                holder.checks = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojacheck);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.checks.setFocusable(false);

            if (listData.get(position).isselected) {
                holder.checks.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.checks.setChecked(false);
            }

            holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {
                    System.out.println("hello" + listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_AMOUNT());
                    dialog = new Dialog(PoojaSelection.this);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name);
                    ImageView cal = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgcalndr);
                    final TextView textcal = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dt);
                    TextView textdays = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_days);
                    String amt = aList.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_AMOUNT();
                    String pojjaday = aList.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_DAYS();
                    pojjaid = aList.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_ID();
                    String pojjanms = aList.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME();
                    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(PoojaSelection.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            sYear = year;
                            sMonth = monthOfYear;
                            sDate = dayOfMonth;
                            textcal.setText(new StringBuilder()
                                    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                                    .append(sYear).append("-").append(sMonth + 1).append("-").append(sDate));
                            selecdts = textcal.getText().toString();
                        }
                    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                    cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            datePickerDialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    textdays.setText("Available Days " + pojjaday);
                    text.setText(pojjanms);
                    TextView dialogButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_wishafriend);
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            holder.showsdates.setText(selecdts);
                            if (selecdts != null) {

                                new LOADPOINTS().execute();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(PoojaSelection.this, "Date Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();

                    if (checkMaxLimit()) {

                        if (listData.get(position).isselected && b) {
                            holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                            listData.get(position).isselected = false;

                        } else {
                            holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                            listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Max limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (b) {
                            listData.get(position).isselected = true;
                        } else {
                            listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });



            holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME());

            return convertView;
        }

        public boolean checkMaxLimit() {
            int countermax = 0;
            for(ModelPooja item : listData){
                if(item.isselected){
                    countermax++;
                }
            }
            return countermax >= 5;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv;
            public CheckBox checks;
             TextView showsdates;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you check in datasource, the 6th item have `listData.get(position).isSelected()` return false

Comment: you can write a logcat or use debug to see the listdata

Comment: @PhanVănLinh any idea ??

Comment: now, i don't have any idea. but try remove 2 lines
holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder.checks.setFocusable(false);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105986/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-albert).

Comment: @allbert what happend with your problem. did it solve or not

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `getViewMethod()` like this ( I only add 2 lines to your code, please see the comment)

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    dtlist=new ArrayList<String>();
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poojaselection, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaname);
        holder.showsdates = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selecteddatess);
        holder.checks = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojacheck);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.checks.setFocusable(false);

    if (listData.get(position).isselected) {
        holder.checks.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {
            System.out.println("hello" + listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_AMOUNT());
            dialog = new Dialog(PoojaSelection.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name);
            ImageView cal = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgcalndr);
            final TextView textcal = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dt);
            TextView textdays = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_days);
            String amt = listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_AMOUNT();
            String pojjaday = listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_DAYS();
            pojjaid = listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_ID();
            String pojjanms = listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME();
            Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(PoojaSelection.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    sYear = year;
                    sMonth = monthOfYear;
                    sDate = dayOfMonth;
                    textcal.setText(new StringBuilder()
                            .append(sYear).append("-").append(sMonth + 1).append("-").append(sDate));
                    selecdts = textcal.getText().toString();
                }
            }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });

            textdays.setText("Available Days " + pojjaday);
            text.setText(pojjanms);
            TextView dialogButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_wishafriend);
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listData.get(position).setSelectedDate(selecdts); // I ADD THIS
                    holder.showsdates.setText(selecdts);
                    if (selecdts != null) {

                        new LOADPOINTS().execute();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PoojaSelection.this, "Date Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

            if (checkMaxLimit()) {

                if (listData.get(position).isselected && b) {
                    holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                    listData.get(position).isselected = false;

                } else {
                    holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                    listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Max limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (b) {
                    listData.get(position).isselected = true;
                } else {
                    listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });


    holder.showsdates.setText(listData.get(position).getSelectedDate()); // I ADD THIS
    holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME());
    Log.i("TAG",position+" - "+listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME());
    return convertView;
}
```

Also create field `selectedDate` in `ModelPooja`

```
public class ModelPooja {

...
    private String selectedDate;

    public void setSelectedDate(String selectedDate) {
        this.selectedDate = selectedDate;
    }

    public String getSelectedDate() {
        return selectedDate;
    }
...
}
```

It work. Hope this help